# If I email a post containing images to a SharePoint 2010 blog, the images get stripped. This didn't happen in 2007. Anyone got a fix/workaround?

Tags: blog, site

We have a requirement to forward on certain emails coming into the company so that our sales guys all see it. To save us hitting all their mailboxes with it, we email enabled the posts list in a SharePoint 2007 blog and they got the content through RSS.

We upgrade to SharePoint 2010 and, although you can still email-enable the blogs post list, it seems you can only send text! No images get through.

Has anyone else seen this or can maybe help with a workaround? Sales managers in several countries more than a bit narked that they have to copy and paste the email into Word/LiveWriter and post from there.